# Preg matching $_FILES

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to capture the scans from  $_FILES, because there will be always passed an empty scan input name and the varry of other can change, I need to get the $_FILES name's and the number. Do you have any advice how to accomplish that?

```
// Skipping the empty scan, and getting the 0-100 possible
$results = preg_grep('/^scan\d{1,2}$/', $_FILES);
```

Generates Array to string conversion error

The post dump

```
["scan0"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "2.jpeg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD7B4.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(24618)
  }
  ["scan1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "2.jpeg"
    ["type"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpD7B5.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(24618)
  }
  ["scan"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you already tried to use `foreach` loop for iterating over `$_FILES` and use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to extract the name and the number of your files?

Comment: Gonna try that, wanted do that after preg_match

Comment: Well need to get the [scan0] like things first.

Comment: You dont need to. Look at the error value on the 'empty' can. The process is to check the error number. if not zero then don't process otherwise do the move_uploaded_file(). The only real thing you need to worry about is that duplicate filenames will overwrite each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scankeys = [];

foreach($scans as $key => $scan)
{
  if(preg_match("/^scan[0-9]{1,2}$/", $key)){
    $scankeys[] = $key;
  }
}
```

I should mention that this is better than trying to combine multiple array manipulation functions to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the `array_filter` with flag will work only for PHP versions >= 5.6

```
$scans = array_filter($_FILES, function ($key, $scan) {
    return $key != 'otherscan' && !empty($scan['name']);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

$names = array_combine(
    array_keys($scans),
    array_map(function ($scan) {
        return $scan['size'];
    }, $scans)
);

var_dump($names);
```

Comment: Well I do not want to get the $scan['name'], I want to get the key above it, so the scan0 array, that's why I want to get only $_FILES['/^scan\d{1,2}$/'] like

Comment: This might be good, but as said I need to get the element name not the name itself.

Comment: array_filter only removes the empty element.. array_keys gets what you actually need.. `scan0`, `scan1`..

Comment: Oh, indeed tell me how can I remove also the $_FILES['otherscan'] from the filter

Comment: I've added the full solution but the array_filter might not work if you have a PHP version lower than 5.6